grid-template-areas shows Invalid property value error?
I'm creating a vijesti.html page with a CSS Grid layout for displaying three types of news items:
grid for less than 800px
grid for wider than 800px
Main News (.mainNews) spans the full width. It should have a 1:2 aspect ratio on screens wider than 800px, and 1:1 on smaller screens.
Vertical News (.verticalNews) is 25% width on screens wider than 800px, 50% on smaller screens, and its height is always double the width.
Square News (.squareNews) has equal width and height, taking up 25% width on large screens and 50% on smaller screens.
I'm trying to use grid-template-areas for this but getting "Invalid property value" errors. How can I properly set up grid-template-areas for this layout, or is there a better approach?
This is the code I've written for it :
<body>
    <div class="news">
        <div class="mainNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
    </div>
</body>

body {
    background-color: #cdc3a9;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.news {
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "main main main main"
    "vertical square square vertical"
    "vertical square square vertical"
    "square square vertical vertical"
    "square square vertical vertical"
}

.mainNews {
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: #c9daf8;
}

.verticalNews {
    grid-area: vertical;
    background-color: #fff2cc;
}

.squareNews {
    grid-area:square;
    background-color: #f4cccc;
}

I plan on adding media query later, my first step was to solve this.

This is my suggestion, the detailed explanation is at the bottom.
HTML Structure:
<body>
    <div class="news">
        <div class="mainNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="squareNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
        <div class="verticalNews">Vijest</div>
    </div>
</body>

CSS:
body {
    background-color: #cdc3a9;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.news {
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "main main main main"
        "vertical square square vertical"
        "vertical square square vertical"
        "square square vertical vertical"
        "square square vertical vertical";
}

.mainNews {
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: #c9daf8;
    /* Aspect ratio 2:1 for larger screens */
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
}

.verticalNews {
    grid-area: vertical;
    background-color: #fff2cc;
    /* Aspect ratio 1:2 */
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
}

.squareNews {
    grid-area: square;
    background-color: #f4cccc;
    /* Aspect ratio 1:1 */
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

/* Media query for screens smaller than 800px */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .news {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas:
            "main main"
            "vertical vertical"
            "square square"
            "square square"
            "square square";
    }

    .mainNews {
        aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* Change to 1:1 for smaller screens */
    }

    .verticalNews {
        /* Change to 50% width on smaller screens */
        grid-column: span 2;
        aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
    }

    .squareNews {
        grid-column: span 1;
    }
}

Explanation:

Setting Aspect Ratios:

aspect-ratio is used for each type of news item to control its width-to-height ratio. For example, .mainNews has a 2:1 aspect ratio on wider screens and changes to 1:1 in the media query for screens smaller than 800px.


Media Query Adjustments:

Inside the media query, the layout is switched to a 2-column grid (grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);).
The grid areas are rearranged to fit the narrower layout, with the .mainNews and .verticalNews elements spanning the full width.


Grid Areas for Repeated Elements:

Since grid-template-areas is designed to create a basic grid template layout, it doesn't automatically account for individual, repeated elements like squareNews and verticalNews. These items are styled according to their class but are placed in the grid using the defined areas.




The media queries weren't the problem, the way I defined "grid-template-areas" was making the problem. As the other person responded ..."Unless those cells form a rectangle, the declaration is invalid". And me having "vertical square square vertical" in the same row, confused the template with the verticals that are separated.

You are missing a ; at the end of your last template area line.
You also have a problem with your areas layout that is causing the error. According to the mdn for grid-template-areas documentation: "Unless those cells form a rectangle, the declaration is invalid".

That ; was there, probably got messed up while i was making the post. So the problem is that the grid doesnt know which vertical to put where? Basically I’ll have to name every “news” for their own, even the square ones? Because there are 8 different square news
